# Select data from MySQL table base on id from other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like this:

```
comic_bookmark
+------+----------+
| user |  comic   |
+------+----------+
|  1   |   1      |
|  1   |   3      |
+------+----------+

comic_comics
+---+---------------+---------------+
| id|   name        |   slug        |
+---+---------------+---------------+
| 1 |   Superman    |   super-man   |
| 2 |   Batman      |   bat-man     |
| 3 |   Spiderman   |   spider-man  |
+---+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to make the result for `id 1` bookmark list show like this:

```
- Spiderman
- Superman
```

I have tried some examples for joining queries but still have no results.
This is my latest try before I asked this question here:

```
<?

    $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT  a.name, b.comic
    FROM    comic_bookmark b
        INNER JOIN comic_comics a
            ON a.id = b.comic
    WHERE  b.user = 1 ");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

?>

<table class="table">

<td><a href="comic-<?$row['slug']?>.html">Test Output: <?$row['name']?></a></td>

<? } ?>
```

I'm really new into this so please help me.

Comment: Please  format the table as code too in order to make it more readable

Comment: `<?$row['name']?>` really? do you mean `<?=$row['name']; ?>` or even better is ` <?php echo $row['name'];?>`

Comment: and why your `<table>` tag is inside the loop?? and where is your `<tr>` tag?

Comment: i need to fetch result in tables so i will got all the result if i had user with a lot of bookmark, already tried outside the loop, the tables only show 1 result, so far `<?php echo $row['name'];?>` now given me the bookmark id but not the name.

Comment: aaah i got it..thanks alex.. thank you verymuch.